# How can I define the input parameter for T32 init script with Practice?

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I am using Eclipse plugin T32 to interface my Lauterbach, in this way I would like to add as input parameter the binary to be loaded by Lauterbach in my target; however I am not able to achieve this and I am wondering why.

I am using this snippet in the load.cmm script to process the input, I have tried with `PARAMTERS` and with `ENTRY` commands but it seems not to work

```
// Using PARAMETERS in Eclipse plugin the call to the script should be xxx.cmm "C:\LocalData\Projects\build\a.elf"
PARAMETERS &elfLocation 

// Using ENTRY in Eclipse plugin the call to the script should be xxx.cmm C:\LocalData\Projects\build\a.elf
//ENTRY &elfLocation 

Data.load.Elf &elfLocation
```

My Eclipse plugin is configured like below
[image]

What I am doing wrong? Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the PRACTICE macro declared before use, e.g `LOCAL &elfLocation`? If not, `ENTRY &elfLocation` will throw an error. `PARAMETERS &elfLocation` would try to declare the macro implicitly instead. To see what happens at start: `<path-to-t32marm> -s C:\LocalData\Projects\build\load.cmm "C:\LocalData\Projects\build\a.elf"`  After start the commands **PMACRO** and **PLIST** will tell you where the script got stuck.

Comment: hi @xasc thanks for replying, yes I was defining it, but no luck so far. I was also wondering, do you know the syntax to follow in the plugin on Eclopse? SHould the input parameter be quoted?